# Reverse String q

Tags: vb.net

Hi I am trying to reverse string in VB.Net WITHOUT using any built-in functions.
this is my c

```
Dim word As String

Dim reversed As String
Dim x As String
Dim count As Integer = Len(word)
Function reverse(ByVal value As String) As String
    Do
        For i = count To 1 Step -1
            x = Mid(word, i + 1, 1)
            reversed = x
        Next
    Loop Until count = 1
    Return reversed
End Function
Sub Main()
    Dim word As String

    Console.WriteLine("Enter word")
    word = Console.ReadLine()

    Console.WriteLine(reverse(word))
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

However my code is not working. Can someone explain me where I am wrong?

Comment: Hi, you'll need to be specific about what is not working - edit the question to include a sample input, the expected output, and the actual output.

Comment: Isn't `Mid` a built-in function? :)

Comment: Your question makes no sense and your knowledge of the language is **minimal**. Your code will be slower than String.Reverse. Apart of this, replace your loop contents with `reverse &= word.Chars(i)`. You also must decrease count by 1. `count = word.Length - 1` (`Len` is VB6, as well as `Mid`). You should also make `reversed` **local** to your method.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem looks like it is in this loop:

```
For i = count To 1 Step -1
    x = Mid(word, i + 1, 1)
    reversed = x
Next
```

You need to *append* `x` onto `reversed`, not replace it, e.g. initialise `reversed` to an empty string with

```
Dim reversed As String = String.Empty
```

then change the line in the loop to

```
reversed = String.Concat(reversed, x)
```

---

Better yet, the [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder) class is **ideal** for repeatedly adding strings together like you are.

Answer (score 1):

You could use **LINQ** extensions.

```
Dim str As String = "Hello World!"

Dim reversed As String = String.Join("", str.Reverse)

Debug.WriteLine(reversed)
```

If you want a more "rustic" approach then:

```
''' <summary>
''' Reverses the characters of the specified string.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="value">The string to reverse.</param>
''' <returns>the reversed string.</returns>
Public Shared Function Reverse(ByVal value As String) As String

    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder

    For Each c As Char In value
        sb.Insert(0, c)
    Next c

    Return sb.ToString

End Function
```

Comment: You've got a typo in `Public` **Dhared** `Function`. :)

Comment: Thanks for the advise, feel free to edit and fix answers next time.